# Volt/load meter - DAQ question

Tags: voltage-measurement, load, daq

I have an analog output from a FANUC Variable Frequency Drive that gives a voltage in the range 0-10v depending on the load. I've cut & paste the relevant parts of [the manual](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Icarus/DOCUMENTS/Fanuc_Manuals_2034.pdf) below.

I would like to replace the volt-meter with a DAQ & record changes in load.

Would this simply be matter of replacing the meter with the below or am I being naive?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is written the internal resistance of the voltmeter should be 10 kΩ and the measurement range be 10 V.

If your (unspecified) DAQ system is capable of reading 10 V then you should place the 10k parallel to it, not in series as you showed.

Also take care that the ground potential on (18)="0M" is not harming your DAQ system. Is the machine grounded? What is it?

Comment: Its a CNC machine in a workshop. I'm assuming its grounded but I'll make sure. The DAQ will either be National Instruments or an MCC172 from Diligent. How would the machine ground affect the DAQ system?

Comment: Afaiks your DAQ has no isolated input. The DAQ systems ground can either be grounded (relate to PE) or be free floating depending on the power supply used. Therefore there is a chance for a ground loop. A ground loop could disturb your measurement, or even killl your DAQ. Check that before connecting them, does M0 relate to PE or N? Does DAQ GND relate to the same potential?